# Восстановление БД Apache-Cassandra

Tags: linux, apache, резервное-копирование, восстановление, cassandra

У меня есть кластер Apache-Cassandra (v3.11.2) состоящий из 6 нод, на каждой из этих нод я сделал бэкап кейспейса 'test'. Каким образом можно восстановить забэкапленные данные с шести нод на одной отдельной ноде кассандры?

Благодарю за внимание.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Это можно сделать через [`sstableloader`](https://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra/3.0/cassandra/tools/toolsBulkloader.html) который идет в составе Cassandra.  Эта программа берет имя keyspace и таблицы из иерархии каталогов, так что надо будет организовать данные соответствующим образом:

```
test/table-name/*-files...
```

Если бэкап был сделан через `nodetool snapshot`, то в `sstableloader` есть ошибка при работе со снапшотами (хотя предполагается что она должна уметь работать и со снапшотами). для этого надо будет сделать следующее:

1. где-то создать каталог с названием keyspace
2. сделать внутрь этого каталога symlink с названием таблицы
3. запустить sstable loader с соответствующими ключами

Полностью:

```
mkdir /var/tmp/data-load/test
ln -s ....test/table-<uuid>/snapshots/<snapshot-name> /var/tmp/data-load/test/<table-name>
sstableloader -d <IP-ноды> /var/tmp/data-load/test/<table-name>
```

Comment: Благодарю вас за ответ, очень полезная информация.